# Apache Virtual Host Limit

Tags: windows, apache-1.3

I'm become the maintainer for an older Apache 1.3 development server running on a Windows XP machine. For some reason, the system won't allow more than a certain number of virtual hosts(in this case 64). I noted in Apache documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#fdlim) that this is possibly due to File Descriptor Limits. However there doesn't seem to be any information on how to adjust this limit on more modern Windows machines. What options do I have for bypassing this limit?

Comment: name based, ip based, or port based virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows they're called file handles, and the registry value is

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\USERProcessHandleQuota

take a backup before editing the registry!

Here is an informative post on the matter: [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)

If you can find a pattern in your vhosts you could create vhost alias rules (AFAIK there is no limit there)